# empty data when using jQuery to get data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to get data from my table and put it inside my modal using jQuery i'm getting only half of the rows without any problem, i can't get other rows from my table ,they r all empty in modal for whatever reason. I'm pretty sure it's selly mistak that i could not find the solution. Your help is much appreciated

Here my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ //getting data from form and put it inside modal
    $(document).on('click','button[data-role=create]', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var paiment =  $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=paiment]').text();
        var rest2 =  $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=rest2]').text();
        var studentid =  $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=studentid]');

        console.log(paiment);

        $('#paiment').val(paiment);
        $('#rest2').val(rest2);
        $('#studentid').val(studentid);
        $('#userid').val(id);

        $('#myModal2').modal('toggle');
    });
});
```

my table :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table2">
                <thead>
                  <tr>

                    <th scope="col">Paiment mensual(DH)</th>
                    <th scope="col">Le rest(DH)</th>  
                    <th scope="col">Total</th>                   
                    <th scope="col">dure de paiment</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date de paiment</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>

                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                   <tr>

                   <th id="val3"></th>
                    <th id="val4"></th>
                     <th id="val5" > </th>
                   <th></th>
                   <th ></th>

                 </tr>
               </tfoot>
              <tbody>


                   @foreach($studentsM as $student)

                   <tr id="{{$student->id}}">  
                    <td width="160" data-target="paiment">{{$student->payment->payment_mois}}</td>
                    <td data-target="rest2">{{$student->payment->Rpayment_mois}}</td>
                    <td ></td>

                    <td width="110">{{$student->payment->Apayment_mois}} Mois</td>
                    <td width="150" id="xd">{{$student->Dpayment_mois}}</td>
                    <td> <button href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-role="create" data-target="#myModal2" data-id="{{$student->id}}">Editer</button></td>

                   </tr>

                   @endforeach
              </tbody>
             </table>
```

My modal:

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inscription">Paiment mensual</lable>
       <input type="text" name="paiment"  class="form-control" id="paiment">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="rest">Le rest</lable>
       <input type="text" name="rest"  class="form-control" id="rest2">
       </div>

       <input type="hidden" id="userid"  class="form-control" >


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-success " href="#" id="save2">Save</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I hope my code is clear enough for you.

UPDATE:

here is what this looks like, the left table is working fine my problem is in right table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE9ZP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cIIP.png)

Comment: I tried your code in a fiddle and it does seem to work ( http://jsfiddle.net/s9yrb4v6/ ) . Check the page source if it the first row contains a ID?

Comment: Please note that the `@foreach ..... @endforeach` is not helpful in trying to figure out what's going on. It's more helpful to post valid HTML extracted from the browser.  ...... Do you mean to say you're not able to get the *column headings*?

Comment: i'm using laravel thats why there is @foreach

Comment: I'm getting data from database.

Comment: Ijust found out that it's not just the first row its almost half of them, I have 8 rows only 2end and 3rd and last row are wodrking.

Comment: Can we at least see row 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: it's in the html page above, i will try to put pictures to be more clear.

Comment: you can check now.